# Button generated with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a list of buttons with this instruction:

```
$("ul#cards").append("<li><button id="modifiedCard" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left">Modified</button></li>");
```

Ok, it works. Buttons are generated correctly.

In the same page I wrote:

```
$("#modifiedCard").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
});
```

But, when I click on one of them the alert doesn't start.

I tried with:

```
<button id="modifiedCard">Try</button>
```

and the alert starts.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added DOM:

```
$("ul#cards").on('click','#modifiedCard',function () {
  alert("Hello!");
});
```

Also note that you are appending the elements. That will generate buttons with same ID. which is invalid markup. IDs should be always unique. I would rather suggest you to use `modifiedCard` as classname instead of ID

```
$("ul#cards").append("<li><button type="button" class="modifiedCard btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left">Modified</button></li>");
```

and then use class selector for event delegation. Like this:

```
$("ul#cards").on('click','.modifiedCard',function () {
  alert("Hello!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Delegate events**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#modifiedCard', function () {
  alert("Hello!");
});
```

Or specifically:

```
$("ul#cards").on('click', '#modifiedCard', function () {
  alert("Hello!");
});
```